# Symfony the page is not found

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with my Symfony project, my page is not found but when I check the list of the routes I find the name of my route I don't understand why? I share with you my code:

```
<?php
// src/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

and my routes:

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::hello
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

I try this url: `http://projetstage/lucky/number`

Comment: i try this url http://projetstage/lucky/number

Comment: Use the builtin server "bin/console server:run" to test your code.  Pretty sure you are trying to use an apache server and you skipped the section in the docs on configuring it.

Comment: thank you for you answer. i use it but it s still not working . When i used      php bin/console server:run i have this message [ok] Server listening on htpp://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Used what?  And what does "not working" mean?  Maybe part of the actual error message?  And how did you check the list of routes?  And you using literally "/lucky/number" and not something like "/lucky/42"?

Comment: when i used the url : projetstage/lucky/number i have this error message Not Found

The requested URL /projetstage/public/lucky/number was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) PHP/7.1.16 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, read the docs on setting an apache server or use the builtin server.  This has nothing to do with your routes.  It is a server configuration issue.

Comment: thank you. i have found my mistake i forgot to use composer require symfony/apache-pack

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using yaml for configure your routes, you should suffix the function name in your Controller class by `Action`
Try to rename function number to `numberAction`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're running your application with an app server like wamp or xampp.

Remember that when you use this app servers you need to instal apache pack like this:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```